# Ext JS Search possibility in MultiSelect ComboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I want to know that how in ExtJS MultiSelect ComboBox i can search for a value. Like if i have entered 's' then a list of items starting with a must be displayed and the item selector should select if it matches with 's'.

This is the code i tried.....

```
    cbCfg = {
      name  : property.columnname,  
      hideOnSelect  : false,  
      triggerAction : 'all',  
      mode      : 'local',  
      width     : comboFieldSize,  
      store     : new Ext.data.SimpleStore({  
          id            : 0,  
          fields        : ['strValue','strText'],  
          data          : data  
      }),  
      listWidth     : 400,  
      valueField        : 'strValue',  
      displayField  : 'strText'  
    };  
    field       = new form.MultiCombo(cbCfg);
```

thnkz in advance,

just:-)

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code in there as a code block - it's really hard to read in comments.

Comment: i updated qn..cn u check it plz?

Comment: @justNeo It would be great to see a reference to `MultiSelect ComboBox` component(sources) as it isn't default part of ExtJS 3.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `MultiSelect ComboBox` extends functionality of `Ext.form.ComboBox`.

You could try going with `triggerAction : 'query'`, which is the default - it should filter out non-matching entries. Although that could be a little bit counter-intuitive for the user.

Another possible approach is adding `typeAhead : true` property - should trigger suggesting suggestions based on the text entered by user.